# Get error in cdc.ddl_history table when add column in Source table

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, dml, change-data-capture

When I am adding a new column in the Source table which I make CDC on that table.
but when I add a column and delete that column. after that when I add the same column in a table that time gets an error in `CDC.ddl_history` table.

Error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'ddl_history_clustered_idx'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'cdc.ddl_history'. The duplicate key value is (684281943, 0x000025d50023c0a80062).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: probably a dumb question but why do you want to do this " but when I add a column and delete that column. after that when I add the same column in a table"

Comment: I want to test it. how to work CDC and what is a limitation.

Comment: but how often would you perform that operation? I'd say, very rarely.